# gas execution status remains "running"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that works fine, but status remains "running". Duration is 3.066 s.

- Why doesnt it go to "Completed"?
- Does it do any harm or does somewhere a process really keep on running? Or should I just ignore this?

```
function doGet() {
  var thisFileId = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);
  var  parentFolder = thisFile.getParents().next().getName(); 

  SPREADSHEET_ID__CONFIGURATION = 'xxx';
  var ssConfig = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID__CONFIGURATION);
  var sheetConfig = ssConfig.getSheetByName('Parameters');

  var configurationHeaders = sheetConfig.getRange(1,1,1,sheetConfig.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var parameters = sheetConfig.getRange(1,configurationHeaders[0].indexOf('Parameter')+1,sheetConfig.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var values = sheetConfig.getRange(1,configurationHeaders[0].indexOf(parentFolder)+1,sheetConfig.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var cVar = [];
  for (p in parameters){
    cVar[parameters[p]] = values[p];
    Logger.log(cVar[cVar[parameters[p]]]);
  }

  p = Number(p) + 1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(cVar['SPREADSHEET__ID__ORDERS_CUSTOMERS']);
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Parameters');
  sht.clearContents();
  sht.getRange(1,1,p).setValues(parameters);
  sht.getRange(1,2,p).setValues(values);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Parameters in file KK in folder '+parentFolder+' should be updated now. Please do manual/visual double-check.');
}
```

Comment: Can you please share sample data that you are running so that I can understand your concern better?

Comment: I imagine you're concerned that the execution log does not go to completed immediately after execution is complete.  I find that the page needs to be refreshed.  Often this problem is worsened by those that employed a vpn that caches pages.  Just refresh the page.  It's one of the not so nice features of working on a server.

Comment: Seems indeed that just refreshing helps